# New badge proposal: "Master Jedi"

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

**Ok, I'm totally not sold on the name, so please recommend another one...**  .

> My current naming idea is to call it
>   the ***Master Jedi*** ***award***. 
>   The message could be something along
>   the lines of:  The user has felt the
>   force among our empire...

I'm thinking this "Master Jedi" badge would given to users who max out their reputation on 3 of the 4 SO sites in a couple day period (2 to 3 days).  The badge would be awarded in each of the user's profiles where their rep was maxed out.

I think that this should at least be a silver badge, but could certainly be a gold.

Comment: Are you Jon Skeet/insert-10k-plus-user-here in disguise? :)

Comment: Maybe the Jeddi badge? following along the idea of trilogy and star wars....

Comment: Still a good idea though.

Comment: @person-b: I think Jon tweeted something on this earlier, but it would be an interesting one...

Comment: "Stud" wouldn't be a great name for the lady badge collectors. Oh wait...

Comment: Totally agree "stud" is not something I'm in love with.  We could call it the "Skeeter"

Comment: I removed references to Stud above....

Comment: Why does it have to be on the Trinity sites (+ meta)? Should someone get the badge if they make the requirements on Cooking, Sci-Fi, and Mathematics?

Comment: @smcg Because this question is over 3 years old. Those sites did not exist then.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw whoops. That'll learn me to check the dates.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose it depends on whether Jeff, Joel and gang want to reward that form of behaviour. It seems that they want great programmers asking and answering great programming questions on stackoverflow, they want great sysadmins asking and answering great sysadmin questions on serverfault and so on. Does it matter so much if one person is [perceived to be] a great programmer *and* a great sysadmin? Personally I don't see this adding much to any of the sites (though it could be seen as reinforcing cliquism, if any exists or is perceived).

Comment: Are you telling me that a great programmer can't possibly answer questions on META, SF, or SU?  There are quite a few jack of all trades out there...

Comment: No, I'm not saying they can't possibly. I'm asking whether it matters if they can or not; I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with this is that you would have a possibility of trying to assign a badge (or multiple badges) across multiple sites.

If this was something that was seriously considered, I would suggest adding a threshold of days to it. I know just personally that it is ridiculously easy to max out on certain sites per day. There has not been a single day on Meta so far that I have not hit rep limit, and I hit rep limit on SuperUser very easily. If I started paying more attention to SO again, I could probably max out there (I am getting almost 50 rep a day not doing anything as it is).

So I would say "Max Out On 3 Sites [X] Amount of Times" and then award your badges. You could also scale it so one day would earn you the bronze version, 10 days would give you the silver, and 30 days would give you the gold.

Comment: I should note that I intentionally only said 3 sites for greedy reasons. I hardly ever use ServerFault, so it would be next to impossible for me to max out on that site along with the other 3 :P

Comment: lol - same for me...  I thought about saying all 4, but SF would be difficult...